# polynomial in 2 variable representing irreducible polynomial over one variable

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x,t)$ be a polynomial with coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}[x,t]$. I am wondering how to check for irreducibility of $f(x,t)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Any help is kindly acknowledged. Thank you

Comment: What sense does it make for a polynomial in $x$ and $t$ to have coefficients that are polynomials in $x$ and $t$? Did you just mean to write that the coefficients are integers?

Comment: I was wondering some thing like $f(x,t)=a(t)x^2+b(t)x+c(t)$,  where $ a(t), b(t), c(t) $  are from  $Z[t]$

Comment: OK, but then that's what you should write. You could write $f$ is in $({\bf Z}[t])[x]$. But that's the same, isn't it, as saying $f$ is in ${\bf Z}[x,t]$, or just saying $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $t$ with integer coefficients, right?

Comment: yes, got it. Thank you